# Move custom format to toolbar in tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have custom format in my formats dropdown, which works well. How do i add this format as a button to my toolbar?

my custom format looks like

```
custom_caption: {title: 'image caption', inline: 'span', classes: 'caption'}
```

i tried to add to

```
toolbar: 'someb_default_buttons | custom_caption'
```

but that didnt work

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    toolbar: "customFormat",
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.addButton('customFormat', {
            text: 'My custom formatting',
            icon: false,
            onclick: function() {
                // Add the custom formatting
                editor.formatter.toggle('custom_caption');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**update**

Have a look at [this fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/tdeaab)

I gues this is what you want. With this fiddle you can select some text, hit the `My Custom Formatting` button, and the text will be surrounded with a `<span class="caption">`.

Comment: i've tried this, way, this style is toggle, like most others, this solution works only for apply-kind styles